# Javascript onscroll funtion not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi Im making a website and i have a fixed header and i want two scnarios, one is wen user scrolls active link changes and the other is when user cliks the page scrolls and active link changes.

I have done the click event and Works fine, but the onscroll event not working.

here is my page code:

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="theme-color" content="#651d31" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

<title>Lux Villa</title>
<link href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    // hide #back-top first
    $("#back-top").hide();

    // fade in #back-top
    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 600) {
                $('#back-top').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('#back-top').fadeOut();
            }
        });

        // scroll body to 0px on click
        $('#back-top a').click(function () {
            $('body,html').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 800);
            return false;
        });
    });

});
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

    //smoothscroll
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).off("scroll");

        $('a').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        })
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var target = this.hash,
            menu = target;
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
        }, 800, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
            $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
        });
    });
});

function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('#menu a').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('#menu li a').removeClass("active");
            currLink.addClass("active");
        }
        else{
            currLink.removeClass("active");
        }
    });
}
</script>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#CCC">
<nav>
<ul id="menu">
  <li style="float:left"><a href="http://brunoferreira.esy.es/v2"><img src="favicon.ico"></a></li>
  <li><a href="sobre nos.html">Sobre n&oacute;s</a></li>
  <li><a href="#casas">Casas</a></li>

  <li><a href="#inicio" class="active">In&iacute;cio</a></li>

  <form style="float:right; margin-right:5px; margin-top:7px;" action="http://brunoferreira.esy.es/v2/search/" method="post">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Pesquisar casas..." name="q">
</form>

</ul>
</nav>
<div id="inicio">
<link href="cssslider_files/csss_engine1/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="cssslider_files/csss_engine1/gestures.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <div class='csslider1 autoplay '>
        <input name="cs_anchor1" id='cs_slide1_0' type="radio" class='cs_anchor slide' >
        <input name="cs_anchor1" id='cs_slide1_1' type="radio" class='cs_anchor slide' >
        <input name="cs_anchor1" id='cs_slide1_2' type="radio" class='cs_anchor slide' >
        <input name="cs_anchor1" id='cs_play1' type="radio" class='cs_anchor' checked>
        <input name="cs_anchor1" id='cs_pause1_0' type="radio" class='cs_anchor pause'>
        <input name="cs_anchor1" id='cs_pause1_1' type="radio" class='cs_anchor pause'>
        <input name="cs_anchor1" id='cs_pause1_2' type="radio" class='cs_anchor pause'>
        <ul>
            <li class="cs_skeleton"><img style="width: 100%;" src="casa3.jpg"></li>
            <li class='num0 img slide'>  <a href="casa1.html" target="_self"><img src="casa1.jpg" alt='Braga' title='Braga' /> </a> </li>
            <li class='num1 img slide'>  <a href="casa8.html" target="_self"><img src="casa8.jpg" alt='Porto' title='Porto' /> </a> </li>
            <li class='num2 img slide'>  <a href="casa10.html" target="_self"><img src="casa10.jpg" alt='Porto' title='Porto' /> </a> </li>
        </ul><div class="cs_engine"></div>
        <div class='cs_description'>
            <label class='num0'><span class="cs_title"><span class="cs_wrapper">1.100.000 &euro;</span></span></label>
            <label class='num1'><span class="cs_title"><span class="cs_wrapper">3.200.000 &euro;</span></span></label>
            <label class='num2'><span class="cs_title"><span class="cs_wrapper">1.600.000 &euro;</span></span></label>
        </div>
        <div class='cs_arrowprev'>
            <label class='num0' for='cs_slide1_0'><span><i></i><b></b></span></label>
            <label class='num1' for='cs_slide1_1'><span><i></i><b></b></span></label>
            <label class='num2' for='cs_slide1_2'><span><i></i><b></b></span></label>
        </div>
        <div class='cs_arrownext'>
            <label class='num0' for='cs_slide1_0'><span><i></i><b></b></span></label>
            <label class='num1' for='cs_slide1_1'><span><i></i><b></b></span></label>
            <label class='num2' for='cs_slide1_2'><span><i></i><b></b></span></label>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
<div id="casas">
<div style="background:#CCC; width:100%; min-height:100px; margin-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px; overflow: hidden;">

<?php
define("servername","mysql.hostinger.pt");
define("username","username");
define("password","password");
define("dbname","dbname");

// Create connection

$conn =new mysqli(servername, username, password, dbname);

// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {

    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

}

$sql ="SELECT id, imgURL, local,preco,infocasa,linkcasa FROM casas ORDER BY casas.id DESC";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $imgurl, $local, $preco, $infocasa, $linkcasa);


while($stmt->fetch()) 
{
     /*echo " - Name: " . $row["local"]. " " . $row["preco"]. "<br>";*/

    echo '<div class="caixacasas">
          <div id="imagem" style="display:inline-block;"><a href="'. $linkcasa.'">
          <img width="250px" height="200px" src="'.$imgurl.'" class="imagenscaixas"></a>
          <p style="margin-top: 10px !important;">'. $local.'</p>'.
          '<p style="margin-top: 10px !important;">'. $preco.'</p>
          </div></div>';
}

$stmt->close();
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
</div>
</div>     
        <footer id="contactos">
        <p style="font-style:italic"><font color="#651D31">Contactos</font></p>
        <div style="margin: 0 auto;  font-style:italic; width: 50%; padding-top:40px;">
        <blockquote>
          <a target="new" href="https://github.com/brunomassa/Luxvilla-web"><button class="btn"><span><svg style="width:39px;height:39px;" viewBox="-3 -14 35 35">
    <path fill="#ffffff" d="M12,2A10,10 0 0,0 2,12C2,16.42 4.87,20.17 8.84,21.5C9.34,21.58 9.5,21.27 9.5,21C9.5,20.77 9.5,20.14 9.5,19.31C6.73,19.91 6.14,17.97 6.14,17.97C5.68,16.81 5.03,16.5 5.03,16.5C4.12,15.88 5.1,15.9 5.1,15.9C6.1,15.97 6.63,16.93 6.63,16.93C7.5,18.45 8.97,18 9.54,17.76C9.63,17.11 9.89,16.67 10.17,16.42C7.95,16.17 5.62,15.31 5.62,11.5C5.62,10.39 6,9.5 6.65,8.79C6.55,8.54 6.2,7.5 6.75,6.15C6.75,6.15 7.59,5.88 9.5,7.17C10.29,6.95 11.15,6.84 12,6.84C12.85,6.84 13.71,6.95 14.5,7.17C16.41,5.88 17.25,6.15 17.25,6.15C17.8,7.5 17.45,8.54 17.35,8.79C18,9.5 18.38,10.39 18.38,11.5C18.38,15.32 16.04,16.16 13.81,16.41C14.17,16.72 14.5,17.33 14.5,18.26C14.5,19.6 14.5,20.68 14.5,21C14.5,21.27 14.66,21.59 15.17,21.5C19.14,20.16 22,16.42 22,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,2Z" />
</svg><font size="5" color="#FFFFFF"> github (Code)</font></span></button></a>
&nbsp;
       <a target="new" href="https://github.com/brunomassa/LuxVilla"><button class="btn"><span><svg style="width:39px;height:39px;" viewBox="-3 -14 35 35">
    <path fill="#ffffff" d="M12,2A10,10 0 0,0 2,12C2,16.42 4.87,20.17 8.84,21.5C9.34,21.58 9.5,21.27 9.5,21C9.5,20.77 9.5,20.14 9.5,19.31C6.73,19.91 6.14,17.97 6.14,17.97C5.68,16.81 5.03,16.5 5.03,16.5C4.12,15.88 5.1,15.9 5.1,15.9C6.1,15.97 6.63,16.93 6.63,16.93C7.5,18.45 8.97,18 9.54,17.76C9.63,17.11 9.89,16.67 10.17,16.42C7.95,16.17 5.62,15.31 5.62,11.5C5.62,10.39 6,9.5 6.65,8.79C6.55,8.54 6.2,7.5 6.75,6.15C6.75,6.15 7.59,5.88 9.5,7.17C10.29,6.95 11.15,6.84 12,6.84C12.85,6.84 13.71,6.95 14.5,7.17C16.41,5.88 17.25,6.15 17.25,6.15C17.8,7.5 17.45,8.54 17.35,8.79C18,9.5 18.38,10.39 18.38,11.5C18.38,15.32 16.04,16.16 13.81,16.41C14.17,16.72 14.5,17.33 14.5,18.26C14.5,19.6 14.5,20.68 14.5,21C14.5,21.27 14.66,21.59 15.17,21.5C19.14,20.16 22,16.42 22,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,2Z" />
</svg><font size="5" color="#FFFFFF"> github (Android)</font></span></button></a>
        </div>
</footer>
<p id="back-top">
        <a href="#inicio"><span></span></a>
    </p></body>
</html>
```

And my website link: [Website Link](http://brunoferreira.esy.es/v2/)

Thanks!

Comment: console is reporting 'refElement.position(...) is null'. Ensure that this isn't null and it should work

Comment: I try to find why is null but dont find why can you or anyone explain why is null.

Comment: underneath `var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));` put console.log(refElement);` what does it return?